# error LSF: undefined symbol: _ZN3ajn15_RemoteEndpoint17 [alljoyn]

Tags: alljoyn

I have a trouble with LSF alljoyn 15.04, I build LSF in ubuntu 16.04 success but I cannot run any app. I'm receiving Notification whenever I run the `./lighting_controller_client_sample` in `service_framework-15.04/core/service_framework/build/linux/standard_core_library/lighting_controller_client/samples`:

> ./lighting_controller_client_sample: symbol lookup error:
>   ./lighting_controller_client_sample: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN3ajn15_RemoteEndpoint17PushMessageRouterERN3qcc10ManagedObjINS_8_MessageEEERm

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your question is completely unclear to me. Include essential part of code in your question.

Comment: Sorry Sir!   my english not good enough,    i download from allseen and  keep everything intact, i build it with scons BINDINGS=cpp OS=Linux CPU=x86_64 Ws=off,  everything is success, but when i run any app i have the error                                                                                   "undefined symbol: _ZN3ajn15_RemoteEndpoint17PushMessageRouterERN3qcc10ManagedObjINS_8_MessageEEERm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it can't find cpp libs (the .a and .so files).
In which case you need to define LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

For example, if you are building alljoyn with scons, then define the following environment variable before running your sample.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/release/dist/cpp/lib

or

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/core/alljoyn/build/linux/x86_64/debug/dist/cpp/lib

That will at least allow it to find the alljoyn cpp lib files.